# How to deploy a react app on digital ocean?

Tags: reactjs, nginx, deployment, digital-ocean

I am new in react and I haven't use digital ocean before to deploy any code.

I want to deploy a react app on digital ocean. After some research I went through some tutorial and documentation but I couldn't able to get step by step guide in easy language. Going through some videos and documentation I got to know that it can be possible by `nginx` and it also provide `ssl` certificate. Also, I wanted to connect to my domain which is on digital ocean as well. I referred this [documentation](https://medium.com/@mixpeal/simplest-way-to-deploy-reactjs-web-app-to-digital-ocean-to-production-adfb9f1667ed).

Steps that I did -

1. React app build `npm run build`.
2. Installed `node.js` on digital ocean.
3. Installed `npm` on digital ocean.
4. Downloaded and install `nginx`.
5. `PM2` used on server.

After doing all this steps, I can't able load my app. It shows broken links of assets.

***Note:I am using digital ocean's console.***

Comment: Could you elaborate more about the broken links? Are you able to get the first page loaded using your domain?

Comment: It seems like it is not getting css and js file paths. I have changed my code temporary to php.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot or error you have?

Comment: Did you use create-create-app to setup your react app?

Comment: Yes. I have created a app.

Comment: you should be using a nginx reverse proxy to your PM2 running app

Comment: The comment above is the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need PM2 for your React app deployment, you can just use Nginx.

`npm run build` creates a build directory with a production build of your app.

And update `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default` with the below content:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        server_name _;
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;

        root  ABSOLUTE_PATH_TO_YOUR_BUILD_DIRECTORY;
        index  index.html index.htm;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }
}
```

Now restart the `nginx` and you will see your app running on the ip address of your droplet.

```
sudo service nginx restart
```